# How to choose the selector type while using many classes in jquery?

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, show

I'm trying to make a page with some Points in it.

E.g:

- Point1
- Point2
- Point3

Each one of these points has some text that is hidden, until we click on the Point, it's then shown below it.

I used the slidetoggle Effect in jquery, but I don't know how to specify that just the selected point will be shown alone. Now, when I press any of them, they are all opened at the same time.

I used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".point").click(function(){
$(".explanation").slideToggle("fast");
});
});
```

So, any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is the element with `explanation` class related to the element with `point` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the `explanation` object that is associated with the clicked on point.  You can get the clicked on point within the click handler by using `this`.   You didn't show you HTML so I'll have to make up an example to show you how:

```
<div class="point>
    other HTML here
    <div class="explanation">
        This is the explanation for this point.
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".point").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".explanation").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

If you want a more specific answer, post your HTML so we can see how the `explanation` object is related to the `point` object in your HTML.  This assumes the explanation is inside the point object.  If it's a sibling, it would take slightly different jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked :)
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".point").click(function(){
        $(this).next.slideToggle("fast");
    });
});

Comment: @user1293474 - Since you're new here on SO, do you realize that you should select which answer helped you the most and click the checkmark next to it to mark it as the "best answer"?  This both rewards that person with some reputation points and gives you some reputation points for following the correct procedure on your question.

Comment: Ah, Ok ... I'm sorry, didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).children(".explanation").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".point").click(function(e){
$(e.srcElement).children(".explanation").slideToggle("fast");
});
});
```

if `.explanation` element is not child of `.point` use `$(e.srcElement.parentNode)`

Answer (score 0):

It Worked :) 
Thanks a lot for your help
Here is the code in case somebody needs it:

Html Code:

```
    <h1 class="point">AAAA</h1>
    <div class="explanation">
    <h3>XXXXX</h3>
    <p>....</p>
    </div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".point").click(function(){
        $(this).next.slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Css:

```
    div.explanation,h1.point
    {
      margin:0px;
      padding:5px;
      text-align:center;
      background:#488AC7;
      border:solid 1px #F6358A;
     }
     div.explanation
     {
      height:120px;
      display:none;
     }
```